# Concat a lot of panda data frames with same columns and same indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of big data frames,around 7 thousands. These data frames are stock prices for dates from 1965 till 2017. I am using first column which is date as index. There are another three columns: Low price,high price and volume for each day. I am accessing all of them in a loop and every time i am looking at a different date window. For example from 1965 through 1970. Is there any way to merge all my data frames in one? What i want is for every date to have: low, high, volume with the name of each stock. That would be more efficient. An important think is that for some stocks some dates are missing, so the number of rows isn't the same for every one. I am thinking something like a list containing all stocks prices for all dates. Here are my data:
https://www.kaggle.com/borismarjanovic/price-volume-data-for-all-us-stocks-etfs/metadata

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the first file. Rename thecolumns to include _pex

```
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/Data/ETFs/pex.us.txt')
renamed = ['Date']
renamed += [str(col) + '_pex' for col in df.columns[1:]]
df.columns = renamed
```

Then you can loop through the files, each time giving the suffix that is the stock name that you get from the file name. And you merge that with the original data frame like this:

```
counter = 0
for filename in os.listdir('/kaggle/input/Data/ETFs/'):
    if filename == 'pex.us.txt':
        continue
    name = (filename.split('.')[0])
    data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/Data/ETFs/'+filename)
    renamed = ['Date']
    renamed += [str(col) + '_' + name for col in data.columns[1:]]
    data.columns = renamed
    df = pd.merge(df, data, on='Date', how='outer')
    counter +=1
    if counter == 5:
        break
```

Notice I put a counter so you could stop and see results, make changes and try again.
I ran out of time on kaggle's online notebook thingy, then when I said 'reconnect' I got a different directory, I am not sure whats up with that but hopefully you get the idea. When you do a how='outer' join, the row of dates that you get in the merged df should be a union of dates from both dataframes being merged, so that should solve the issue of not all dates being same in each file.